# New Instagram API: empty data on /tags/TAGNAME/media/recent

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, instagram, instagram-api

i wrote a module for Drupal 7 with instagram images flow (based on a configuration of a hastag). Given the Client application registered on developers site and redirect urls configured correctly i managed to get the Access_token and finally got to use it on my front-end.
But the problem is that API returns me empty data!

I've read that there're new rules and policies after November, 17 2015 for applications that are ALL now require access_token to make ANY type of request on Instagram API. More info [here](https://instagram.com/developer/sandbox/)

- I did Explicit authorization (server-side) flow.
- Yes i did specified the scopes during the Authorization cycle (basic + public_content)

Call:
    https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/TAG_NAME/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

giving me the result:
HTTP Status: 200

```
{
  meta: { code: 200 }
  data: {
    media_count: 1466
    name: "TAG_NAME"
  }
}
```

Why ?

Thx for help if any1 sees this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you in Sandbox mode?

If so:

> The behavior of the API when you are in sandbox mode is the same as when your app is live, but comes with the following restrictions:
>
> - Data is restricted to sandbox users and the 20 most recent media from each sandbox user
> - Reduced API rate limits

Meaning, if your sandbox user(s) have no images with that tag, the data won't be shown.

Comment: Ahh, there we go. Thank you! I was having a similar problem. I couldn't believe there were no posts about #starwars, especially after Ep7 came out. ;D

Comment: @twined which mean when my app is live, `tags/{tag-name}/media/recent` 's will fetch public hash tag instead of sandbox user's hashtag?

Comment: @Mavichow yes, that is if you get your app through the validation process and out of sandbox mode.